# Ajax trigger keyup function changing to instant trigger

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i'm trying to get details information from database according to input from *id_card* .
im already succeed getting the information after I'm typing the id_card in the input box by using keyup function. What i need to do now is I want result appear without I have to press any key after input was trigger. As information, the input will fill in by using QR scanner.

My HTML

```
<input type="text" id="id_card" placeholder="Capture by QR Code Scanner" name="id_card">
<input type="text" id="fullname" placeholder="Staf Name" name="fullname" readonly>
```

My Ajax

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#id_card').keyup(function() {
    var id_card = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
      url: "<?php echo base_url('index.php/scan/get_details'); ?>",
      method: 'post',
      data: {id_card: id_card},
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(response) {
        var len = response.length;

        document.getElementById("fullname").value = "";

        if (len > 0) {
          $("#id_card").load();
          var uname = response[0].id_card;
          var name = response[0].fullname;

          document.getElementById("fullname").value = response[0].fullname;
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

I'm trying to change keyup function to onchange but no luck.

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$(function() {
   $('#id_card').on("input", function(e) { // pasted or typed
   let id_card = $(this).val();
   if (id_card.replace(/\D+/g).length < 16) return 
   // here the ajax
```

Comment: result appear when I'm typed & paste the id, but if i scan the qr code card & id placed in the input box, no result appear, i need to re-type then result displayed. Could u guide how to make sure the ID Card textbox triggered any changes or event occur in the box then result will appear?

Comment: Try `$('#id_card').on("input", function() {..... }).focus();` to get focus on page load

Comment: Still need to press enter key

Comment: Press enter key to what? Trigger the input event?